# Why doesn't the php command "include" work?

Tags: php, html

We have created at a course a website with several html pages. We have used php to introduce items in the database, read from the database and so on.

And now as we want the nav and footer sections to be the same for all the pages and have the same links, we have created php files that include the nav and the footer section and we included them into the html pages.

nav

```
<?php
    echo "<h1>Categorii</h1>";
        echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li><a href=\"buchete.php\">Buchete</a></li>",;
            echo "<li><a href=\"aranjamente.php\">Aranjamente</a></li>";
            echo "<li>Bonsai</li>";
            echo "<li>Promotii</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "<h1>Mai puteti cumpara...</h1>";
        echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li>Dulciuri</li>";
            echo "<li>Bauturi</li>";
            echo "<li>Jucarii</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "<h1>Cele mai bine vandute</h1>";
        echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li>2009</li>";
            echo "<li>2008</li>";
            echo "<li>2007</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "<h1>Administrare</h1>";
        echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li><a href=\"login.php\">Baza de date</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "<h1>Impresii</h1>";
        echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li><a href=\"opinie.php\">Carte de oaspeti</a></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
?>
```

footer

```
<?php
echo"<p>Sait proiectat de Informatica aplicata si programare.&nbsp;&nbsp; &copy; I.A.P. 2014 </p>"
?>
```

We wrote scripts that include each file in the section and included the scripts in each html file.

```
<nav> 
<?php
include 'navigare.php';
?>
</nav>
```

We transformed the html files in php files. None of the pages show the nav and the footer section.

I changed the links in the nav section to go to the php files not the html files. Why don't the pages show the nav and footer section?

Comment: On error_reporting()

Comment: U have a syntax error in footer.Php missing semi colon

Comment: 1. You can parse HTML without having to echo it, do `?>HTML here<?php` (don't have to go into PHP unless you're gonna use it). 2. When you use `include 'navigare.php';`, you assume that the file is in the same folder. If it's not, you have to adjust for paths. Also, it might be *case-sensitive* (depends on the server OS), and has to be exact.

Comment: @devpro: No, the `?>` does that for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma in:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"buchete.php\">Buchete</a></li>",;
```

Comment: Also missing semi colon in footer.php